# Calling a PHP file from a PHP loop in background

Tags: php, curl, post, call, synchronous

I have a PHP loop where i need to call another PHP file in the background to insert/update some information based on a variable send to it. I have tried to use CURL, but it does not seem to work.

I need it to call SQLupdate.php?symbol=$symbol - Is there another way of calling that PHP with the paramter in the background - and can it eventually be done Synchronously with a response back for each loop?

```
while(($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) and ($counter < $max))
{
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "SQLinsert.php",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'symbol' => $symbol,

    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Where is the "other PHP file" located?  Might be as simple as "include()" ...

Comment: Incidentally, this looks rather "un-performant" ...

Comment: Yes, so is there another way of doing it? I need to call that phpfile like 100 times in the loop. Include does not work, as it will print the phpfile to the screen.

Comment: *Where* is the file located, and what code is in it?

Comment: First `include_once('/path/to/SQLinsert.php');` then go into your loop and use any function that was in SQLinsert.php.

Comment: Although I still have no information about your issue, I can certainly make a few suggestions for the approach you're trying.  Init CURL prior to the loop and close it after the loop.  Use a complete, web-accessible URL instead of a simple filename.  Do all the cURL config before the loop except adjusting the POSTFIELDS inside it.

An alternative approach might be file_get_contents().

Comment: The file is located in the same folder - Brian how do i call that insert function in SQLinsert.php - i only need to call it with the parameter ?symbol=$symbol for it to know what to do...

Comment: Maybe you should rethink what you actual want from this `SQLinsert.php`? Maybe you could wrap the stuff inside the file into a function or even better a class and call that function doing the business logic.

Comment: And yes you could call include, buffer the output and discard the buffer, but I highly recommend not to do this, only becuase you want to execute the logic inside the file. Try to seperate the logic files from the output files

Comment: What actually isn't working?

Comment: Nothing happens and no errors?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey I did what you suggested now i get curl_setopt_array(): 4 is not a valid cURL handle resource error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to weigh in down here in hopes of getting this one "away & done".

Although it isn't entirely clear from your post, it seems you're trying to call your PHP file via an HTTP(s) protocol.

In many configurations of PHP, you could do this and avoid some potential cURL overhead by using file_get_contents() instead:

```
while(($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) and ($counter < $max)) {

    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'symbol' => $row['symbol']
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/SQLinsert.php', false, $context);

    $counter++; // you didn't mention this, but you don't want a everloop...
}
```

That's pretty much a textbook example copied from the manual, actually.

To use cURL instead, as you tried to do originally, and in truth it seems pretty clean with one call to curl_setopt() inside the loop:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://example.com/SQLinsert.php",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);

while(($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) and ($counter < $max)) {

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('symbol' => $row['symbol']));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $counter++; //see above
}
// do this *after* the loop
curl_close($ch);
```

Now **the actual and original problem may be that $symbol isn't initialized**; at least, it isn't in the example you have provided.  I've attempted to fix this by using *$row['symbol']* in both my examples.  If this isn't the name of the column in the database then you would obviously need to use the correct name.

Finally, be advised that it's almost always better to access a secondary resource via the fastest available mechanism; if "SQLinsert.php" is local to the calling script, using HTTP(s) is going to be terribly under-performant, and you should rewrite both pieces of the system to work from a local (e.g. 'disk-based') point-of-view (which has already been recommended by a plethora of commenters):

```
//SQLinsert.php
function myInsert($symbol) {
    // you've not given us any DB schema information ...
    global $db; //hack, *cough*
    $sql = "insert into `myTable` (symbol) values('$symbol')";
    $res = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($res) return true;
    return false;
}

//script.php

require_once("SQLinsert.php");

while(($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) and ($counter < $max)) {

    $ins = myInsert($row['symbol']);

    if ($ins) { // let's only count *good* inserts, which is possible
               // because we've written 'myInsert' to return a boolean
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a very thorough answer - it works fine!